# Cannot connect to COM port in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, serial-port

I am running a code for my FPGA to collect data from accelerometer and I am able to print that to Tera Term. And I followed [this tutorial](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28941-real-time-data-plot-from-serial-port?focused=5166995&tab=function) to have MATLAB plot the data in real time.

I have essentially used the same code except a few changes in variable names title.

It gives me the following error.

The mathwork website has a similar question posted but there is no solution.

> Open failed: Cannot connect to the COM6 port. Possible reasons are
>   another application is connected to the port or the port does not
>   exist.
>
> Error in Untitled (line 8) fopen(s);

TIA

Comment: The error message is telling you something. Have you verified that none of those reasons are valid for your case?

Comment: Are you able to connect to this COM port using any other tool?

Comment: You can see if the com exists in Device Manager. If all looks well I would restart the program / PC